# Change the values of itemssource at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have two buttons and combobox:

```
<Button Click="Btn2_Click"/>
<Button Click="Btn_Click"/>
<ComboBox x:Name="myCombo"  IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True" Text="-- Choose --"   SelectionChanged="MyCombo_SelectionChanged"/>
```

The class looks like:

```
private List<string> lst;
public Page2()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   lst = new List<string>();
   myCombo.ItemsSource = lst; //set the combobox itemsource to the list content
}

private void Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  //clear all from list and from combobox
  lst.Clear();
  if (myCombo.Items.Count > 0)
     myCombo.Items.Clear();

   for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
      lst.Add(i.ToString());//add some content to the list
}

private void Btn2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  //clear all from list and from combobox
  lst.Clear();
  if (myCombo.Items.Count > 0)
     myCombo.Items.Clear();

   for(int i=10;i<20;i++) //add some other content to the list
     lst.Add(i.ToString());
}
```

My question: when I click btn1 then I see in combobox the values `0,1,...9`, and if I click after on btn2 I still see the same `0,1,...9` values.

that's not what I want, I want that when I click btn2 I want in the combobox `10,11,...,19`,

what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Replace `List<string>` with `ObservableCollection<string>`
2. You've already set `myCombo.ItemsSource` to lst, so no need manually update its `Items` as well. Just add to / clear the lst collection and the control will automatically update.